Refreshable closure not having access to model? Is this a bug?
I've come along a strange behaviour of .refreshable that is illustrated with the code below:
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var cntrl=ContentViewController()
    
    @State private var counter=0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                counter+=1
                cntrl.setValue(counter)
            } label: {
                Text("Increase value")
            }
            
            
            Text("Selected value local: \(counter)")
            Text("Selected value cntrl: \(cntrl.model.selectedValue)")
            NewView(model: cntrl.model)
        }
        
    }
    
    
}

struct NewView:View {
    let model:Model
    
    @State private var valueSetByFunc:Int=0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                whatIsTheValue()
            } label: {
                Text("Call func")
            }
            List {
                Text("Value set by func: \(valueSetByFunc)")
            }.refreshable {
                whatIsTheValue()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func whatIsTheValue() {
        valueSetByFunc=model.selectedValue
    }
}

struct Model {
    var selectedValue=0
    
    mutating func setValue(_ value:Int) {
        self.selectedValue=value
    }
}

@Observable
class ContentViewController {
    var model=Model()
    
    func setValue(_ value:Int) {
        self.model.setValue(value)
    }
}

Hello, I am trying to understand the following behaviour of .refreshable.
If you try the code posted, and click on "increase value", you will get respective fields being updated correctly.
If you then click on the "call func" button, that updates the valueSetByFunc, it correctly updates the value in the "NewView" by calling whatIsTheValue().
But if you "pull to refresh", that calls the same function whatIsTheValue(), suddenly the value returned is different.
Does anybody know if this is correct behaviour?

Hmm, NewView didn't rerender when refreshing, however, the @State was reset to zero, and the model.selectedValue still holds some value. I cannot give you an explanation but @workingdog answer could fix this.

Maybe the reason for this inconsistent behavior is that .refreshable is meant to be used in a asynchronous context such as making a call to a rest api or fetching from a database

But in my opinion, it still does not explain why I should not be able to access a "let" "model" of the view. The problem is that I want to trigger an action with the .refresh based on the model.  So "refreshing" looks at the model, and requests data from the server based on the state of the model which now seems is not possible... If I ever get a reply from Apple, I will post here.

You need to pass a Binding to your NewView.
Try this approach to update the cntrl.model in all views:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var cntrl = ContentViewController()
    @State private var counter = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                counter += 1
                cntrl.setValue(counter)
            } label: {
                Text("Increase value")
            }
            Text("Selected value local: \(counter)")
            Text("Selected value cntrl: \(cntrl.model.selectedValue)")
            NewView(model: $cntrl.model) // <-- here $
        }
    }
}

struct NewView:View {
    @Binding var model: Model  // <-- here
    @State private var valueSetByFunc: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                whatIsTheValue()
            } label: {
                Text("Call func")
            }
            List {
                Text("Value set by func: \(valueSetByFunc)")
            }.refreshable {
                whatIsTheValue()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func whatIsTheValue() {
        valueSetByFunc = model.selectedValue
    }
}

An alternative that also works, is to keep your original code but change Model to:
@Observable class Model {
    var selectedValue = 0
    
    func setValue(_ value: Int) {
        selectedValue = value
    }
}


If this is the solution then why did it work when the button was pressed in NewView?

why did it work when the button was pressed in NewView, I don't know for sure
why a Button action function call behaves differently to calling the
same function in a view modifier. I suspect it is due to the async nature of .refreshable,
from the docs "...an asynchronous handler that SwiftUI executes when the user requests a refresh".

Thanks for your comments. As the "Model" in the original code is a struct and making it a class is not an option at the moment, I will wait a bit more if someone comes up with an explanation. I posted it as a bug to Apple. It "feels" wrong that calling the same function requesting a "let value" from different parts of the same view renders different results. But thanks for your time.

ok, note my answer works well with struct Model

Hello workingdog support Ukraine, I accepted your answer with @Binding as it solves the problem. Thanks for your review. Let's see if feedback from Apple arrives that this is intended behaviour for .refreshable. Thx. Libor
